# Invalid Parameter: SNS.optInPhoneNumber

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to use AWS SNS's `optInPhoneNumber` function. But I am getting this error.

```
    InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: 
    at Request.extractError 
    at Request.callListeners 
    at Request.emit 
    at Request.emit 
    at Request.transition 
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo 
    at 
    at Request.<anonymous> 
    at Request.<anonymous> 
    at Request.callListeners 
    at Request.emit 
    at Request.emit 
    at Request.transition 
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo 
    at Request.<anonymous> 
    at Request.<anonymous> 
    ....
  code: 'InvalidParameter',
  time: 2021-07-30T17:28:08.847Z,
  requestId: '23aa0a5d-7875-5438-b051-5323409d09f4',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 4.786451228396071
```

Here is my Code. Don't worry about the return statement. Just to satisfy the front-end I am passing a hardcoded value.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { parsePhoneNumber } from 'libphonenumber-js';

export const optInPhoneNumber = async (phoneNumber: string) => {
  const client = new AWS.SNS({region: 'us-east-1'});

  const params = {
    phoneNumber: parsePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 'US')?.format('E.164'),
  };

  client
    .optInPhoneNumber(params)
    .promise()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return {
    isError: false,
  };
};
```

EDIT: the passing `phoneNumber:647-XXX-XXXX`. But when I pass phoneNumber as 647-XXX-XXX is passes, which is not a valid number.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I opted out a number and was trying to re opt-in. But in the docs, it says that you can opt for a number every 30 days

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the E.164 format. Try +16470001234.

It's [mentioned in the docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_OptInPhoneNumber.html).

Comment: Yeah. To convert to that format I am using parsePhoneNumber function from libphonenumber-js

Answer (score 1):

A valid phone number is the following format:

phoneNumber - the mobile phone number to look up (for example, +1XXX5550100).\n\n";

Use this format and it will work for you.